# Указатели на функцию

Tags: c, функции, указатели, тернарный-оператор

В параграфе 5.11 K&R "Указатели на функции". есть следующая строка которая ставит меня в тупик

```
qsort((void **)lineptr, 0, nlines - 1, (int (*)(void *, void *)) (numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то если ранее определенный numeric = 1, то в качестве аргумента функции qsort будет вызвана `numcmp (void *, void *)`, в противном случае `strcmp (void *, void *)`, я прав? И если я прав, то где можно почитать о подобного рода конструкции, потому что K&R не дает пояснений по этому поводу.

И второй вопрос. Я правильно понимаю что выражение вида `(void **)lineptr` приводит первый символ первого элемента массива указателей `*lineptr[]` к типу `void`?

Comment: Не вызвана, а передана... Чтоб вызвана - это нужно `(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)(...)`

Comment: @Harry ну то есть в одном случае передана одна функция, во втором другая? Где можно почитать о подобного рода конструкциях? Потому что во всех источниках мне встречаются примеры вида
сначала объявляем некую функцию, например,
int a(int, int);
а затем указатель на нее
int (*a1) = &a;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обычный стандартный тернарный оператор `?:`

```
условие ?  если_да : если_нет
```

выполняет (и возвращает) *если_да* при истинности условия, и *если_нет* при его ложности.

Например,

```
int a = (b > c) ? b : c;
```

Здесь `a` получит значение большей из величин `b` и `c`.

В вашем

```
(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

в случае, если `numeric` истинно (ненулевое), вернет указатель на `numcmp`, в противном случае - указатель на `strcmp` (имя функции неявно преобразуется в указатель на нее).

Кстати, почитайте [эту статейку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/205848/).

Во втором вопросе - просто `lineptr` (который, видимо, представляет собой массив указателей на строки) приводится к виду указатель на указатель на `void` - ну, с натяжкой можно сказать и так, что к типу массива указателей на `void`.

Comment: Как работает тернарный оператор я в курсе. Меня интересует следующее. Допустим numeric = 1. Тогда получается конструкция вида int (*)(void *, void *) numcmp. 

Я бы понял конструкцию типа (numeric : int numcmp (void *, void *) ? int strcmp(void *, void *). А описанное выше похоже на какой-то совершенно варварский синтаксис

Comment: Отнюдь! Вы неверно записали - надо вот так: `(int (*)(void *, void *))numcmp` - видите разницу? Теперь это приведение типа! Может, вам проще будет воспринять так: `typedef int (*function)(void *, void *); (function)numcmp;`? Видите? Это просто приведение типа к указателю на функцию, которой передаются два указателя на `void` и которая возвращает `int` - просто цена обобщенности в C :) Так понятно?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое

Comment: Ну, тогда закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...